# Add error bars to customized barplot function in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, correlation

I have a function to make custom barplots for plotting correlation coefficients that looks like this

```
    olsenbar <- function(i , axisnames = FALSE , data = rs) {
   barplot(
     data[,i] ,
     main = colnames(data)[i] ,
     horiz = TRUE ,
     border = FALSE ,
     space = NULL , col = c ("dimgray") , 
     axes = FALSE ,
     axisnames = axisnames ,
     cex.names = 2 ,
     cex.main = 2 ,
     ylab = "" ,
     xlab = "" ,
     xlim = c(-1,1))
   axis( side = 1 , at = c(-1.0,0,1.0) , cex.axis = 1.6)
   abline( v = 0 , lty = 1 , lwd = 3 , col = grey(0.5))
   abline( v = seq( -1 , 1 , 0.1 ) , lty = 3 )}
```

which I want to apply to some correlatoins looking like the following. The data includes the correlation coefficients and corresponding confidence intervals and p-values with another variable.

```
df
                       lower     r upper    p
Hcy response           -0.28  0.53  0.90 0.18
Cysteine response      -0.48  0.34  0.84 0.41
Methionine response    -0.44  0.38  0.86 0.36
Cystathionine response -0.10  0.65  0.93 0.08
Glutation response     -0.83 -0.31  0.51 0.46
Taurine response       -0.31  0.51  0.89 0.20
```

When I apply the above function to it like so

```
olsenbar( 2 , data = df , axisnames = TRUE )
```

I end up with the following plot

[Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtjMR.png)

However, I would like to enter the corresponding confidence intervals to the bars, but I can't seem to work that out. As I understand, working out error bars for these barplots is a bit tricky, and I can't get it to work no matter what I try. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `ggplot2` an option? Or you have to do this in base R?

Comment: It is, but I prefer to do this in base R to learn a bit more on creating and implementing features in functions etc. I guess in `ggplot2`, you can add the error bars and flip the coordinate system using `coord_flip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(names, r)) +
    geom_col(fill = 'dimgray') +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = .5, size = 1) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1), position = 'top', breaks = c(-1, 0, 1), minor_breaks = seq(-1, 1, .1)) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_line(linetype = 3, colour = 'black'),
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(linetype = 3, colour = 'black'),
          panel.background = element_rect('white')
          )
```

[image]

#### Data:

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'names lower     r upper    p
"Hcy response"           -0.28  0.53  0.90 0.18
                 "Cysteine response"      -0.48  0.34  0.84 0.41
                 "Methionine response"    -0.44  0.38  0.86 0.36
                 "Cystathionine response" -0.10  0.65  0.93 0.08
                 "Glutation response"     -0.83 -0.31  0.51 0.46
                 "Taurine response"       -0.31  0.51  0.89 0.20', h = T)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @GGamba! God I love this place.